# How to create custom address renderer

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address, address, renderer

How to create custom address renderer with the following template in one line
`{{var street}}, {{var city}}, {{var region}} {{var postcode}}, {{var country}}`

I can't change the native address templates, because they are used for order view pages, pdf, etc.

When i try

```
$renderer = Mage::helper('customer/address')->getRenderer(Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Config::DEFAULT_ADDRESS_RENDERER);
$renderer->render($address, $format);
```

i catch `Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in <b>app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php on line 85`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify renderer type one of:

```
const OUTPUT_FORMAT_JSON    = 'json';
const OUTPUT_FORMAT_TEXT    = 'text';
const OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML    = 'html';
const OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF     = 'pdf';
const OUTPUT_FORMAT_ONELINE = 'oneline';
```

Use helper below:

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Helper_Address extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const ADDRESS_FORMAT = '{{var street}}, {{var city}}, {{var region}} {{var postcode}}, {{var country}}';

    public function render($address, $format = null)
    {
        if ($format === null) {
            $format = self::ADDRESS_FORMAT;
        }
        return $this->getRenderer()->render($this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress(), $format);
    }

    /**
     * @return Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default
     */
    protected function _getRenderer()
    {
        $renderer = Mage::helper('customer/address')->getRenderer(Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Config::DEFAULT_ADDRESS_RENDERER);
        $renderer->setType($this->getType());
        return $renderer;
    }

    /**
     * @return Varien_Object
     */
    protected function _getType()
    {
        $type = new Varien_Object(
            array(
                'code' => Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ONELINE,
            )
        );
        return $type;
    }
}
```

Usage `Mage::helper('your_module/address')->render($address, $format)`.